# Lebesgue integral that satisfies $\int_X u=2017$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X u_n=2018$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have to find a sequence of functions that satisfies  $\int_X xd\mu=2017$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X x_nd\mu=2018$ given $(X,A,\mu)$ is a measurable space $\mathcal{M}^+_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}}$ and $x_n\to x$ for $n\to\infty$ (pointwise convergence).

I know from Fatou's lemma that such function exists as it says:
$$\int_X xd\mu\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X x_nd\mu,$$
but I cannot really find such function when $x$ has to be convergent.

Comment: Fatou's lemma doesn't tell you that such function exists, it's just an inequality

Comment: @Jakobian Okay, but then I'm a bit confused, as I then think such function cannot exist due to $\int_X ud\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X u_nd\mu$ when $u$ converges uniformly?

Comment: The 2017 / 2018 issue is irrelevant. You can have $\int_X x d\mu= 0$ and $\int_X x_n d\mu = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Also, the result about uniform convergence implying $L_1$ convergence only applies on finite measure spaces.

Comment: Be careful: Fatou's lemma is only valid for suitable functions. (Positive or bounded by below it's ok)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have $x_n \to x$ uniformly if you like. Define $x_n(t) = \dfrac 1n \chi_{[n,2n)}(t)$. Then $x_n \to 0$ uniformly but $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R} x_n(t) \, dt = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you! A question: What does the indicator funktion $1_{[n,2n)}$ do in $x_n(t)$?